# If A is a n × n matrix, and Ax = 0 has non-trivial solutions, then λ = 0 is an eigenvalue for A.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is this statement true or false? In this context, I am required to provide a simple example showing if it is false, or some sort of basic proof if it is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well, the nontrivial solution $x$ is an eigenvector for $0$.

Comment: If it's alright with you, could you please explain it just a tad more? 
thanks

Comment: Since $x$ is an eigenvector for $0$ we conclude $0$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix. The reason why $x$ is an eigenvector for $0$ is that $Ax=0x=0$.

Comment: that makes 100% sense, and I understand it now. Thank you very much!

Comment: no problem, good luck with your studies.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that's pretty much the definition of eigenvalue.

> $\lambda \in K$ is an eigenvalue of $A \iff \exists v \ne 0: Av = \lambda v$